# Issues with post request using redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a post request in my application, using redux saga middleware.
Now, the code related to my post request looks like this:

```js
function* postNewMessage(newMessage) {
    console.log(newMessage)
    const {var1, var2} = newMessage;
    try {
        const data = yield call(() => {
            return fetch(myapi, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: `application/json`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    first: var1,
                    second: var2
                }),
            })
        });
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}


function* addNewMessageSaga(action) {
    console.log(action)
    try {
         yield postNewMessage(action.newMessage)
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

function* watchNewMessage() {
    takeEvery(POST_MESSAGE, addNewMessageSaga)
}

//bellow is my action which i call in my component

export const postMessage = (newMessage) => {
    console.log(newMessage)
    return {
        type: POST_MESSAGE,
        newMessage
    };
};
```

This is all my code related with post request. Now i call the action inside component like:

```js
postMessageOnApi({
  var1: selector.data,
  var2:selector.data1[0]
})};
```

When i click on the button to  post my data, i get the values only inside `postMessageOnApi`, there console.log() shows my values, but in `function * postNewMessage..` i don't get data. 
Who knows where i made a mistake and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to use `yield` before `takeEvery`

```
function* watchNewMessage() {
    yield takeEvery(POST_MESSAGE, addNewMessageSaga)
}
```

Comment: didn't help. What another issue could be?

Comment: Do you have something logged in the console here `addNewMessageSaga`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try using `call` instead of direct calling `yield postNewMessage(action.newMessage)`. It would be: `yield call(postNewMessage, action.newMessage)`. Or use `yield* postNewMessage(action.newMessage)`

Comment: , the latest working console is in `postMessageOnApi`

Comment: Could you show `postMessageOnApi`? You showed only `postMessage` in the question.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to wrap it to redux dispather?

Comment: sorry, i wanted to say `postMessage` not `postMessageOnApi `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213330/discussion-between-askmen-and-mark-partola).